# Architectural Issue Regarding Iterations

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm working on importing a dataset that looks like:

Quantity
100-500

Processes
litho, plain

Grammage
80, 120

These come in on a single record. The issue is that the above represents 8 different potential prices, one for each combination of each of the variable options, so from this one record we make 8 pricing records:

- 100, litho, 80
- 100, litho, 120
- 100, plain, 80
- 100, plain, 120
- 500, litho, 80
- 500, litho, 120
- 500, plain, 80
- 500, plain, 120

But in reality there are a lot more variables and options, such that this one record results in over 1000 pricing records.

So my question is one of elegant code; is there any typical pattern that this represents and how could it best be modelled in C#?

Comment: I think you are looking for how to do combinatorics in c#. Is this correct?

Comment: You're not going to get many helpful answers by posting a data sample alone. Show us the code you're currently using to process the data (even pseudocode is fine) and then clarify what about it you don't like.

Comment: What is a pricing record? Also, I do not understand your question.

Comment: There is no code as yet, I'm trying to work out how this should be done.

Comment: but the prices aren't stored? The just looks like standard relational data, right? Each `Price` has a many-to-one with `Quantity`, `Process` and `Grammage`.

Comment: The prices are to be stored in the DB. I edited to show the pricing records that would come out of this.

Comment: Okay, so your data is stored in a denormalised way, presumably for "performance" reasons or because the designer was evil/insane.

Comment: I'd start by considering a normalisation of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.noldorin.com/2010/05/combinatorics-in-csharp/

He was some working examples for a GetCombinations() extension for a list. It probably won't solve your problem as is, but it should give you a good starting point on how to deal with combinations. This can be a difficult problem.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need. I'll investigate tomorrow but thank you!

Comment: I've thought about this a little more and it does fit the bill. Amazing!